# Component MSCOMCTL.OCX or one of its dependencies not correctly registered

Tags: vb6

I am trying to run an exe file on Windows 10 which was compiled using VB6 in 2002/2003.
I get:

```
Run-time error:'339':
Component MSCOMCTL.OCX or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid.
```

What are the extra files I need to download and install on Windows 10 to get this running ?
I tried [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Common Controls](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10019) but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the control is not registered properly when the app was installed. ALL VB6 apps must be installed on windows 10 "as administrator" or the controls do not register properly.

On my windows 10 machine it is located in  C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Open a command prompt as administrator.

[image]

Then from the command line run:

C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscomctl.ocx

[image]
This should register the OCX properly. If that does not work comment here and I have a few other things to try.

Comment: The module MSCOMCTL.OCX was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005

Comment: I couldn't find the file MSCOMCTL.OCX after installing VB6 Common Controls so I copied it from MSOffice folder.

Comment: Check which version you have. The version I have is dated 2004-03-08  v6.1.97.82

Comment: version 7.0.55.3227

Comment: Do you have VB6 by chance installed on that PC? The other thing you can try is download sp6 from microsoft and install that as administrator.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721  It will unpack to a folder. There is MSComCtl.CAB which contains that file. But I would try to run setupsp6.exe as administrator. Make sure you delete that other file you copied over manually first.

Comment: There's no VB6 on my PC. This is like a new setup which has Office. https://imgur.com/a/4CFuAep

Comment: @Kim the link you provided is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem started when I downloaded and installed the new common controls from Microsoft, and it ended when I replaced the new mscomctl.ocx with the old one from the sp6 cab file.